# How to identify that a URL path string contains path params in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, url

So what I am trying to do is to identify if a URL path string contains any path params or not. For example:

1. /product/1/detail  ==> this should be identified as true
2. /user/sam/detail ===> this should be identified as true
3. /product ===> this should be identified as false

Further, I will also have a dictionary that is list of similar URl paths ie [ '/company/5/info', '/user/ram/detail']

[
'/product/5/detail',
'/user/ram/detail'
]

I do not know if this will be helpful for checking patterns or any formation.

Constraints:
The URL that is to be checked can be any URL. That is we will not have any such known patterns besides a list of URL's like [ '/product/5/detail', '/user/ram/detail']

Comment: Could you split the string by `/` and check its length to see if any extra paths are included? Eg. `const pathParams = string.split('/').length > 1`

Comment: But that would need us to know the constant paths ahead, which here can be anything, so that would not work

Comment: Well it would work assuming that a URL with path params fit that structure as your example seems to. Are you using a particular routing framework? They might have some inbuilt functionality for this.

Comment: nope, I am detecting this in an express server, and needs to be done only with string manipulation. Yeah peek into any of the framework routings would help and I am researching it but yet not found any solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can get parameter from URL segment like

```
var URL='example.com/product/1/detail';
var arr=URL.split('/');//arr[0]='example.com'
                       //arr[1]='product'
                       //arr[2]='1'
                       //arr[3]='detail'

alert(arr[1]);
```

By making URL as an array. and splitting using /.

Comment: the point is not to grab one as the positions will be abmigious. The input can be any kind of url, So the hardcoded index won't work. And goal is to identify if any provided url has a path param !